# Convert Json to Xml In Android

Tags: java, android, xml, json

I have a .net webservice and web method. When I retrive data from this webmethod it retrieves a JSON file.

How can I convert JSON to XML?

Comment: Bad question, why not parse the JSON or rewrite the web service???

Comment: I don't understand why this is considered "Not a real question". The question is "How can I convert JSON to XML?" Can someone clarify?

Comment: Underscore-java library has static method U.jsonToXml(string). I am the mainteiner of the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [JSON](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) java library to do the conversion with the [XML class](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/). More options available on [json.org](http://json.org/).

Comment: page is now working. 404 error

Comment: fixed links - json.org restructured their docs