# How to convert json data into xml in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, json

I have the following Json data :-

```
[{"accountid":"1-RMNT","name":"NASA"},
{"accountid":"1-XQN9","name":"NewAccount"},
{"accountid":"1-Q9VF","name":"Noratel Communication"},
{"accountid":"1-RNLY","name":"Nordstrom"}]
```

How can I convert this JSON data to XML?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplex method to Convert Json to Xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742705/simplex-method-to-convert-json-to-xml)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743910/convert-json-to-xml-in-android

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct solution, but using gson(JSON to object) and xstream(object to XML) is doable. It may need some extra mapping code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the class XML.java that it´s be included in the package [org.jason](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/XML.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do not think difficult, Its a easy way to convert XML to JSON or JSON to XML, 
Just open http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/ and paste your json codes or xml codes. After paste and press button, then you will get Output. Its very useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) has method `U.jsonToXml(json)`.

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "[{\"accountid\":\"1-RMNT\",\"name\":\"NASA\"},\n"
            + "{\"accountid\":\"1-XQN9\",\"name\":\"NewAccount\"},\n"
            + "{\"accountid\":\"1-Q9VF\",\"name\":\"Noratel Communication\"},\n"
            + "{\"accountid\":\"1-RNLY\",\"name\":\"Nordstrom\"}]";
        System.out.println(U.jsonToXml(json));
    }
}

// <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
// <root>
//   <element>
//     <accountid>1-RMNT</accountid>
//     <name>NASA</name>
//   </element>
//   <element>
//     <accountid>1-XQN9</accountid>
//     <name>NewAccount</name>
//   </element>
//   <element>
//     <accountid>1-Q9VF</accountid>
//     <name>Noratel Communication</name>
//   </element>
//   <element>
//     <accountid>1-RNLY</accountid>
//     <name>Nordstrom</name>
//   </element>
// </root>
```